# CODEOWNERS syntax: /foobar/** vs /foobar/

Tags: github, glob, github-codeowners

Assuming I want to enforce on some directory (e.g. `foobar`) on my git repository hosted on GitHub a code owner. In the `CODEOWNERS` file I can specify:

```
/foobar/** @someuser
```

But also this would be possible:

```
/foobar/ @someuser
```

Is there any difference between these two ways? Is it exactly the same?

Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-code-owners) does not contain any description about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two consecutive asterisks (`**`) in patterns matched against full pathname may have special meaning:

- A leading `**` followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, `**/foo` matches file or directory `foo` anywhere, the same as pattern `foo`. `**/foo/bar` matches file or directory `bar` anywhere that is directly under directory `foo`.
- A trailing `/**` matches everything inside. For example, `abc/**` matches all files inside directory `abc`, relative to the location of the `.gitignore` file, with infinite depth.
- A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, `a/**/b` matches `a/b`, `a/x/b`, `a/x/y/b` and so on.
- Other consecutive asterisks are considered regular asterisks and will match according to the previous rules.

Read more here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format

As far as I can tell both patterns you describe do the same. Since the `CODEOWNERS` file works (almost) the same as `.gitignore` ignoring a folder will ignore all of its sub-folder. So `/foobar/**` and `/foobar/` should be the same.

Comment: This answers 50% of the question. What does `/foobar/ @someuser` mean?

Comment: `/foobar/` makes `@someuser` the code owner for all paths starting with `/foobar/`